# Changes made to Renderscript File not reflecting in Emulator

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

Whenever I make changes to Renderscript and try running the emulator, the changes are not reflecting. I tried clean and build, invalidate the cache and restart but nothing helps. The changes reflect only when I delete the renderscript file and recreate the rs file with a different name, but this is cumbersome to do every time.

Any fix for this? I'm using build tools version 25.0.3 and API 26 in Emulator.

I understand the stack overflow community on renderscript is limited. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of android studio are you using ?

Comment: @QuentinMenini    I'm using version 3.0

Comment: I've not seen this issue specifically. Check to see if your project is using the instant run feature. If it is, try turning it off.

Comment: There was a bug logged regarding behavior like this a little over a year ago, but it was closed because of not enough info from the reporter and unable to duplicate it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37092933

Comment: I had this problem on an old Android Studio version (that's why I asked about the version), it was a problem with Android Studio not checking changes in .rs files (that google fixed in later Android Studio versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Larry Schiefer.

The link he mentioned refers to a similar issue.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37092933

As mentioned in the link, a better alternative to this issue is to uninstall the app from device/emulator before running it.

I've tried this fix and the renderscript changes are getting reflected.